# Two tracking pixel firing on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-dfp

I use DFP adserver with macros to trigger a tracking pixel (Adobe Audience Manager) for a customer. It seems working for all browsers, except that on Google Chrome, where the pixel is firing two times.

See screenshot below, we should only have two pixels, and on Chrome we have four of them (two pixels firing two times, at the exact same moment (d_bust is a timestamp)). Moreover, sometimes, 2 calls are cancelled :

[Pixels firing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8keM.jpg)
Does anyone has an idea why my pixels are firing two times only on Chrome ?

Thanks a lot